# Implementation of velocity transformation during release of an object from a swinging rope

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, physics, xna-4.0, game-physics

I have the following problem in two dimensions:

An object is attached to a rope and moving like a pendulum with the angular velocity V_a (polar angle per second), the rope has a length of L from the attachment point to the object. Now the rope is cut and the velocity of the object that was attached to the rope a moment ago should be smoothly transformed into V_xy, a two-dimensional velocity vector tangential to the circular movement on the rope.

The direction of V_xy is obtained by adding (or substracting, depending on the direction of movement) Pi/2 to the angle between the point of attachment and the object.

However, how can one obtain the absolute value (components) of the vector V_xy such that it corresponds to V_a ?

Lateron, it should be implemented in C#4 and XNA as part of a game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point the pendulum bob gets released (i.e. the rope snaps/is cut) you know the angle that the string makes with the vertical (call it angle A). From this the two values of the velocity are given by:

> v_x = U * cos(A)

and

> v_y = U * sin(A)

where U is the velocity of the bob in the direction of rotation (i.e. perpendicular to the string) at the time of release. If you have the angular velocity V_a and the string length L, then U can be established via:

> U = V_a * L

and the equations above become

> v_x = V_a * L * cos(A)

and

> v_y = V_a * L * sin(A)

I hope this helps.

Comment: there is a need for the factor to compare the orientation of the object at the cut compared to the gravity direction and strength. this will affect the velocity formula as you lose velocity getting away from gravity source

Comment: No, this was not the question. The question is concerning the instantaneous velocities in the x and y direction at the point the rope/string is cut. That is what I have answered. Of course we could go further and discuss how the Earth's rotation will affect the particles path relative to the surface - again this was not the question being asked.

Comment: Yes, Killercam is right, the later transformation by gravity, friction etc. is not part of the question ;-)

Comment: Well i was just mentioning it as there is already classes to calculate ballistic curve made by people on the net that take care of all that. You put in the origin point of the object (when rope get cut). the direction the object was going, the velocity, drag, density... you can default alot of the inputs to a sphere object of X mass if realism is not crucial. and in the end you have a nice graph curve. I had one back in .net 2.0.